# Cross-site scripting: how to check the string

Tags: xss

I have a string. This is the value of some attribute of some html tag.
How to check if this string contains javascript?
For example (SRC attribute of IMG tag):

```
1. <IMG src="javascript:alert('XSS')"> - contains script<br/>
2. <IMG src="JaVaScRiPt:alert('XSS')"> - contains script<br/>
3. <IMG &#106;&#97;&#118;&#97;&#115;&#99;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#116;&#58;&#97;&#108;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#40;&#39;&#88;&#83;&#83;&#39;&#41;> - also contains javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to canonicalize, then check. But i would look at HtmlPurifier or OWASP AntiSamy for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to do, as there are *lots* of odd and tricky ways to sneak JavaScript in.

[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) has pretty complex parsing to filter out all potentially unsafe HTML if you must allow HTML input in the first place.

However, generally you shouldn't even try to do that, and simply **always escape the string**.

In PHP that is:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
```

In JS you can use `document.createTextNode()` or jQuery's equivalent `$(el).text()` to safely insert text into DOM (those two methods don't require escaping).